# A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services

'Hi 
I am calling a web service from javascript/jquery as follows:

```
function Test(userid) {
    alert(userid);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testWebService.asmx/GetData",
        data: "{ userid:'" + userid + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
        alert("1")
        var dATAS = (typeof (response.d)) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
        alert("2")                          

        },
        failure: function (msg) {
        }
    });
}
```

the userid get alerted,

the webservice is tested and it is working, the other alerts doesnt show.

the output shows this:

A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

what Did I have wrong?

**Edit: I copied the function to another existing webservice in the solution, it worked with no problem**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you marked your web service class with [ScriptService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute? Failing to do so will result in an exception - but I am not certain if it would the one that you have got.